# (Apache : couldn't load module) httpd: Syntax error on line 539 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf:Cannot load C:/php/php7apache2_4.dll into server:

Tags: php, apache

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 539 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/php/php7apache2_4.dll into server:The specified module could not be found
```

I am new to apache and php. I did everything till restarting it. I installed it in C driver. When i try to restart it this happens.

line 539 :

```
LoadModule php7_module "C:/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
```

also I don't actually understand the terms. So can you explain a little more clearly please?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem. After installing php 8.0 on Win 32 OS and  Apache 2.4. I tried to link php to apache by adding the php module to httpd.conf file of apache. I added the code below to httpd config file.

```
# PHP8 module
PHPIniDir "C:/PHP"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
LoadModule php8_module C:/PHP/php8apache2_4.dll**
```

After which I tried to restart apache and got an error message in the Apache log error file. Apache refused to start and kept displaying and error message too.

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 519 of C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.4/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.4/modules/php7apache2_4.dll into server: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I fixed the error by doing the following. It appears in Apache 2.4 httpd configuration file, **php8_module** has to be replaced with simply **php_module** without
any number. The code below fixed the error and apache started successfully after modifying the C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.4\conf\mime.types file.

```
# PHP 8.0
PHPIniDir "c:/php"
LoadModule php_module "c:/php/php8apache2_4.dll"
```

Add the following line to the end of the mime.types config file

`application/x-httpd-php              php`

Answer (score 0):

Apache is a webserver. And it uses several modules, roughly similar to plugins to do the work it was programmed to do.

Your case the error it has thrown is that, **the module you have asked apache to load is not found by it**. Hence it has thrown the error.

Going by the error, apache seems to have a conflict with your php installation, which has lead to failure in your case.
Because you have not menitoned your web server architecture, i am assuming that you built a server around apache and php.

You can try to reinstall php, add *essential php extensions* for apache-php linkage and try to rectify in case you're building the server.

Below resources can help you in the process:

[Cannot load C:/php/php7apache2_4.dll into server: %1 is not a valid Win32 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48081104/cannot-load-c-php-php7apache2-4-dll-into-server-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-applic)

[How to enable php7 module in apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988990/how-to-enable-php7-module-in-apache)